# SQL Parse Error: Parameter name expected using firebird

Tags: firebird

I'm using the script in firebird:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
execute block as
declare a_cursor CURSOR FOR(select contaSelect.cdcontacontabil, spedcontavincSelect.nuversao, spedcontavincSelect.cdcontasped
from ectbconta contaSelect join ectbspedcontavinc spedcontavincSelect on contaSelect.cdempresa=spedcontavincSelect.cdempresa and contaSelect.cdconta=spedcontavincSelect.cdconta where contaSelect.cdempresa = 1);
​
declare variable contacontabil varchar(40);
declare variable versao integer;
declare variable contasped integer;
​
begin
    open a_cursor;

    while(1=1) do
    begin
        fetch a_cursor INTO contacontabil, versao, contasped;
        if (row_count = 0) then leave;
        insert into ectbspedcontavinc (cdempresa, cdconta, nuversao, cdcontasped)
        select contaInsert.cdempresa, contaInsert.cdconta, :versao, :contasped from ectbconta contaInsert 
        where contaInsert.cdcontacontabil =:contacontabil and contaInsert.cdempresa in(2, 3,  4)
        and not exists (select * from ectbspedcontavinc spedcontavincInsert 
            where spedcontavincInsert.cdempresa=contaInsert.cdempresa and spedcontavincInsert.cdconta=contaInsert.cdconta and spedcontavincInsert.nuversao=:versao and spedcontavincInsert.cdcontasped=:contasped);
    end
end
^
​
SET TERM ; ^
​
COMMIT WORK;
```

Ocurred this message:

> Error Message:
>   ---------------------------------------- SQL Parse Error:
>
> Parameter name expected
>
> D:\Java\Firebird_2_5\bin>isql.exe -z ISQL Version: WI-V2.5.5.26952
>   Firebird 2.5 Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database SQL>

I don't know what do.

```
public class CriaScriptSpedContaVincService {

private static final Integer GRUPO_EMPRESA_CTB = 3;
private static final Integer CD_EMPRESA_CONSOLIDADORA = 102;

public void criaCriaScriptSpedContaVinc() {
    StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
    IContabEmpresa contabEmpresa = new ContabEmpresaProvider();
    List<Integer> empresas = contabEmpresa.retornaEmpresasDoGrupoContabil(GRUPO_EMPRESA_CTB);
    for (Integer cdEmpresa : empresas) {
        script.append("INSERT INTO ECTBSPEDCONTAVINC (CDEMPRESA, CDCONTA, NUVERSAO, CDCONTASPED) ");
        script.append("SELECT ");
        script.append(cdEmpresa);
        script.append(" AS CDEMPRESA, C.CDCONTA, C.NUVERSAO, C.CDCONTASPED ");
        script.append("FROM ECTBSPEDCONTAVINC C WHERE C.CDEMPRESA = ");
        script.append(CD_EMPRESA_CONSOLIDADORA);
        script.append(" AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ECTBSPEDCONTAVINC CV WHERE CV.CDEMPRESA = ");
        script.append(cdEmpresa);
        script.append(" AND CV.CDCONTA = C.CDCONTA);");
        script.append(TextUtil.NOVA_LINHA);
    }
    String caminhaCompletoArquivo = "t:/xande/script2.sql";
    FileUtil.escreveArquivo(script, caminhaCompletoArquivo);
    System.out.println("Fechou mano... ;)");
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to reduce your code as much as possible to see where the problem occurs? BTW: Why the complicated code with a cursor, when you should be able to achieve the same effect with a single `insert into ... select ...`.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer.
In other old version of firebird the script runs no problem.
I did need to resolve this problem fast, then I did make in java, iterate the data and creating the script.

Comment: I put the abuse code